# Visual Studio 2008 - Cannot find reference to appropriate Crystal Report version

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, gac, .net-assembly

My development laptop was recently exchanged for a newer model.  I have Visual Studio 2005, 2008, & 2010 on this computer.  One of our web applications uses Crystal Reports.  The **web.config** file references version 10.2.3600.0:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

The project solution is still a Visual Studio 2008 solution, but we will eventually upgrade to VS 2010.  The problem I am having is that, when I opened the solution on this new computer, it could not find the Crystal Report assemblies.  When I go to **References->Add New Reference**, the **.NET** tab shows the CrystalDecisions component names, however the Version number is 10.5.3700.0.

When I look in the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly) I see both version 10.2.3600.0 & 10.5.3700.0 as being installed and available.

***How can I make these assemblies (v 10.2.3600.0) available for me to reference within my Visual Studio 2008 project?***

Unfortunately I can't upgrade the project to VS 2010 just yet, and can't upgrade the servers to use the new assembly versions just yet either.

Comment: Mark - can you add a reference to the new CR version if you create a test project in VS2010?

Comment: @KenCenerelli no.  Only the version 10.5.3700.0.